# How i communicate in two server.i want some data from A server to on B server.if i do it through Web socket if yes then how?

Tags: sql-server, linux, server

i want to access the data from server 1 to server 2.how can i do this things,can this possible through the p tunnel.i am try to sudo ptunnel -p 192.168.0.66 -lp 8080 -da 192.168.0.66 -dp 9090 this p tunnel on two server but it gives me error [err]: Failed to bind listening socket: Address already in use.

Answer (score 0):

```
Follow these steps to create a Linked Server:

       Server Objects -> Linked Servers -> New Linked Server
       Provide Remote Server Name.
       Select Remote Server Type (SQL Server or Other).
       Select Security -> Be made using this security context and provide login and password of remote server.
       Click OK and you are done !!
        [HERE][1]ple tutorial for creating a linked server.

       OR

       You can add linked server using query.

       Syntax:

       sp_addlinkedserver [ @server= ] 'server' [ , [ @srvproduct= ] 'product_name' ] 
            [ , [ @provider= ] 'provider_name' ]
            [ , [ @datasrc= ] 'data_source' ] 
            [ , [ @location= ] 'location' ] 
            [ , [ @provstr= ] 'provider_string' ] 
            [ , [ @catalog= ] 'catalog' ] 
       Read more about sp_addlinkedserver.

       You have to create linked server only once. After creating linked server, we can query it as follows:

       select * from LinkedServerName.DatabaseName.OwnerName.TableName
```